# Does the .Net Framework 4.0 Installer include the .Net Framework 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, installation

Do .Net components that were compiled against the .Net Framework 3.5 run on a system that has only .Net Framework 4.0 installed?

Or in other words, does the .Net Framework 4.0 Installer include the .Net Framework 3.5?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816914/about-backward-compatibility-of-net-framework-4) make be helpful to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816914/about-backward-compatibility-of-net-framework-4

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The .NET 4.0 installer doesn't include the .NET framework 3.5.  There is [some information on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx) in MSDN:

> The .NET Framework 4 is highly compatible with applications that are built with earlier .NET Framework versions, except for some changes that were made to improve security, standards compliance, correctness, reliability, and performance.
>
> The .NET Framework 4 does not automatically use its version of the common language runtime to run applications that are built with earlier versions of the .NET Framework. To run older applications with .NET Framework 4, you must compile your application with the target .NET Framework version specified in the properties for your project in Visual Studio, or you can specify the supported runtime with the [`<supportedRuntime>` Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) in an application configuration file.

You can install .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 along side each other. Visual Studio 2010 also includes improved targetting support for .NET 3.5. [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx) talks about this in more detail.

Answer (score 13):

Sure this is very old and late. However sometimes pictures are better than words (provided the links still work).

For more info please see Microsoft's Official page, [NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049).

[image: Dependencies diagram of the .Net Framework]

Answer (score 6):

On XP SP2 with FW 4 installed running FW3.5 application gives a message:

`Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application.`

So the answer is no.

Comment: I think that's a little misleading as it's next to trivial to run a .NET 3.5 app on a .NET 4 runtime. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959743/running-net-3-5-apps-on-net-4-only-systems

Answer (score 1):

See: [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx)

This gives a clear picture what is included in each version of .Net. Also,

> > You do not have to install previous versions of the .NET Framework or the CLR before you install the latest version; each version provides the necessary components.