# CLR Version for Custom Action

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have an InstallShield 2010 basic MSI install with a managed code .dll custom action installed with the application.  The custom action works if I build it with .NET 3.5 but it fails if I build it with 4.0.

I see references to setting the CLR version in the manual but I'm at a loss on how to actually do it in the MSI.

All help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**:

I ran a simple MSI that runs a CA build with .NET version 4, here are a few interesting things picked out of the log:

> Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
>
> Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 5.1.2600.5512
>
> Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.1
>
> ....
>
> MSI (c) (0C:10) [12:12:15:689]: Connected to service for CA interface.
>
> InstallShield: Loaded CLR  successfully
>
> InstallShield: Loading Assembly [#v4.dll]
>
> InstallShield: Resolving assembly filekey [#v4.dll].
>
> InstallShield:  - Resolved to C:\Program Files\My Company Name\My
>   Product Name\V4.dll
>
> InstallShield: Loading assembly from path C:\Program Files\My Company
>   Name\My Product Name\V4.dll
>
> InstallShield: Unable to load managed custom action assembly
>   [#v4.dll]: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program
>   Files\My Company Name\My Product Name\V4.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
>
> Action ended 12:12:15: v4Test. Return value 3.
>
> ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make this work with a 'Managed Assembly' in InstallShield.  I'm still using InstallShield for the installation but I'm using a WiX DTF (Deployment Tools Foundation) custom action and it works well across versions.

Answer (score 1):

On systems that support common language run-time assemblies, the Windows Installer sets the [MsiNetAssemblySupport property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/32f4f971-8e42-46b0-96e4-b3505abd2314) to the latest version of the .NET Framework version on the user's computer. You can check the MsiNetAssemblySupport property for the version, and then install a higher version if your CA requires it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It still doesn't work.  I run the installer with logging and MsiNetAssemblySupport property shows it's values as 4.0.30319.1.  I've added some of the log detail to the question.

Comment: Is this custom action attempting to use [Isolated Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/eb5f7088-30e0-4644-813a-c93e6f56ccbf)? I see [RedirectedDLLSupport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/703489c4-cac4-442c-bd96-d3927491a864) has been set. Perhaps a required dependency is missing.

Comment: There are no dependencies at all.  It's a simple class with one public method:

class CA { public int Execute(string s, string t) { return 55; }};

I don't think I did anything to set RedirectedDLLSupport.  I'm still looking up this and Isolated Components for clues.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think this may not be a Windows Installer issue, you may want to investigate .NET 3/4 backwards compatibility, for example [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816914/backwards-compatibility-of-net-framework-4)