# Deploy C# application for offline computer

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

How can I create the install package for my C# application so that a computer without .NET and without internet can get all the requirements without the use of internet. Basically, is there anything I can do in visual studio to include .NET in my install folder so the user can use my program while not enabling internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include .Net as a prerequisite in a VS Installer Project or an InstallShield project (InstallShield LE is available for free with VS2010). This will automatically create a bootstrap `setup.exe` that installs .Net (if necessary), followed by your installer.

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994427.aspx#vsredistdeploy_topic3) page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to include the .net installer msi and trigger it to install in the package. This would be akin to when you use other installers that trigger secondary installations like DirectX or Crystal Reports, etc.

Since there is no assurance that the user will follow through with the installation of the secondary package, you will need to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include the entire .NET installer with your installer.  Of course this means that your installer will grow significantly in size, but since that is your only option here it seems reasonable.  Also be aware that, if you are targeting .NET 4.0, the installer does not include the .NET 3.5 runtime.  You can include both if needed.

You can get the [redistributable package here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263)

Comment: Im new to .NET, but yes my application targets 4.0. Why would I hae to include 3.5 but I do remember need to this a while back on my old computer.

Comment: You should be fine as you are targeting 3.5 and not 4.0.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803434/does-the-net-framework-4-0-installer-include-the-net-framework-3-5

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
See the MSDN document:
[Using Visual Studio .NET to Redistribute the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994427.aspx)