# Can't Install Powershell 2.0 on XP SP3

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, wmi

I'm trying to install powershell 2.0 on winxp SP3 with .Net Framework 4.0 installed on my machine but I can't install it. It asks for .Net 2.0. It makes no sense to me at all, since I have an upgraded version of such framework. Here's the full message:

"Cannot Install windows powershell v2 because it requires an updated version of the .Net framework. Please, install .Net framework 2.0."

Anyone can lend a hand here? Tnx.

Comment: You can have .NET 4 installed without .NET 2.0 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803434/does-the-net-framework-4-0-installer-include-the-net-framework-3-5). Try installing .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 5):

You need 2.0 installed. 4.0 is a side-by-side version of the .NET CLR. It's not an in-place upgrade, so something that demands 2.0 specifically will not accept 4.0. Confusingly, .NET 3.5 SP1 is the latest version of 2.0 and is what you want.

3.0, 3.5 and 4.5** are not new versions of the CLR (.NET's JRE) and are more like libraries/service packs to CLR2 and CLR4.

** well, actually 4.5 is a bit muddier than that but the comparison is sufficient.