# Does .net framework 3.5 required to install .net framework 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I'm not cleared in the specification of .NET Framework 4.0. As per my knowledge .net framework 3.0 required .net framework 2.0 and .net framework 3.5 required .net framework 3.0, so I'm not cleared that whether .net framework 4.0 required .net framework 3.5? Whether .net framework 4.0 is standalone or not? I had searched most of the Microsoft helpful sites, but not got anything on that topic. Guys, If you know anything please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *every* version of .NET has been standalone. You can install .NET 3.0 with no other version installed, ditto .NET 3.5, ditto 4.0, ditto 4.5 etc.

Now there have been fewer versions of the CLR than there have of the .NET framework overall, but that's a different matter - and doesn't change whether or not you can install .NET without installing anything else.

Likewise some versions of .NET effectively install over the top of others (installing .NET 4.5  when you've got .NET 4.0 installed replaces the .NET 4.0 libraries) but you can still install each version without installing anything else first.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803434/does-the-net-framework-4-0-installer-include-the-net-framework-3-5?rq=1) Hey @Jon Skeet can you look at this link?

Comment: @Akashkumar: Okay, I've looked at it. That just says that the .NET 4.0 installer doesn't also install .NET 3.5. But most .NET 3.5 applications would still just work after installing .NET 4.0, due to the normal backward compatibility features. It *doesn't* mean that you have to install .NET 3.5 before you install .NET 4.0.

Comment: So your statement means .net framework is standalone?

Comment: @Akashkumar: It depends on *exactly* what you mean by standalone. They're standalone in that you can install .NET 4.0 without installing .NET 3.5 first.

Comment: Exactly that's the answer which I'm looking for. Thank You for sharing @Jon Skeet